# Separate jQuery.ajaxSetup() for each $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I set different settings (jQuery.ajaxSetup()) for different AJAX requests?

What I would like to do is to "link" each AJAX call do different ajaxSetup().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of [`$.ajaxSetup()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) is to create default settings for all ajax calls via jQuery on a global scale. If you want to override settings, just specify them in the specific ajax call.

For instance, somewhere early in your code, define your `$.ajaxSetup()`:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    type: 'POST'
    , cache: false
    , contentType: 'application/json'
    , dataType: 'json'
    , error: function (a, b, c) {
        //default error handling
        console.log(a, b, c);       
    }
});
```

Then when you want to override, say, using a `GET`, do something like:

```
$.ajax(myUrl, {
    type: 'GET'
    , data: myData
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that .ajax() has all the same attributes that ajaxSetup() does...

Comment: +1 I like this solution better than Kevin and mine's (<- grammar?) because in most cases, it would be far easier to just set up some defaults and override them as needed. Better than having all sorts of config objects everywhere.

Comment: Yep! they have all the same properties. If you only make one ajax call in your program, you could set all the properties in `$.ajaxSetup()` and just call `$.ajax()` with no params to make your call :)

(I wouldn't recommend it though)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just want to use [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) to merge your inputs into some different defaults that you have set up. For example:

```
var settings1 = {
    type:"GET",
    url:"something.php"
};

var settings2 = {
    type:"POST",
    url: "somethingelse.php"
}

$.ajax($.extend(true, settings1, {
    data: {key: val}
}));

$.ajax($.extend(true, settings2, {
    data: {key: val}
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create separate objects and use those objects to create your options that you pass into `$.ajax`.

```
var ajaxSetup1 = {
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html"
}
$.ajax( $.extend( ajaxSetup1, {"url","mypage.php"} ) );
```

That could of course be wrapped in a private method for re-use.

Comment: I felt you deserved an upvote for the mention of wrapping this in a private method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the documentation on jquery.com about .ajax()? It's amazing how much different settings (as parameters) it takes.
 There's a big chance you can do what you want inside an .ajax() without having to call .ajaxSetup().